# Why my method to store positions from a clicked map in a txt-file doesn't work?

Tags: android, google-maps, file-io

I am trying to store the positions (lat, lng) when i click on a map in a text file, and moreover i will store the file local. But i stuck in how to do that properly! - this is what i am doing:

```
 private void savePositions(LatLng latLng) throws IOException {
        String latitude = String.valueOf(latLng.latitude), longitude = String.valueOf(latLng.longitude);

            ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> position = new ArrayList<>();
            posisjon.add(new Pair<>(latitude, longitude));

            String fileNameInternal = "test.txt";
            String fileDir = "/data/data/com.example.steve.myApp/files/";
            //Delete existing file:
            String fileToDelete = fileDir + fileNameInternal;
            File file = new File(fileToDelete);
            file.delete();
            try {
                fout = this.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(fileNameInternal, Context.MODE_APPEND);
                oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
                for (Pair p : position)
                    oos.writeDouble(Double.valueOf(p));
            } catch (Exception exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (oos != null) {
                        oos.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help is very appreciated. I tried for several hours before posting this request. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting an empty file or no file at all? Are you sure the problem is in this function and not the touch listener?

Comment: Please add your stacktrace to the question... I´d expect you will get an IOException while trying to delete the file.

Comment: My file looks bizarre, something  like this: í {sr  java.io.NotSerializableException(Vx ç†5  xr java.io.ObjectStreamExceptiondÃäk....with 2MB size. I don't understand? i clicked 2 or 3 times on the map. I get an icon to be sure with a title(lat, lng)!

Comment: I don't see how the code you provided compiles. But what I think you are trying to do is to write the `android.util.Pair` to the ObjectOutputStream but this will not work because this class is not serializable.

Comment: i has just written (comment to sebastian) that i doubt it. How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a good idea would be to buffer the locations in memory and then flush it to file at appropriate times instead of writing to file on every touch event.

The method that writes data to disk could look something like this, writing longitude, latitude pair per line.

```
private void flushLocationsToDisk(List<LatLng> locations) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("locations.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
    for (LatLng latLng : locations) {
        String line = latLng.latitude + "," + latLng.longitude;
        bw.write(line);
        bw.newLine();
    }
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: So you would seperate the double value between the longitute and the latitude with a semicolon for example? And after each pair write a '\n' to end the line?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Then you can just read the file line by line and parse the latitude and longitude.

Comment: so it is better to have: List<LatLng> locations than List<Pair<String, String>> locations ? but why?

Comment: If you already have LatLng object there is no need to create another object for the same purpose. Other than memory penalty of creating new unnecessary objects there is no difference.

Comment: yes i understand (it was not relevant question). you are right. another and i hope last question why did you choose to save the file on an internal than an external storage?

Comment: It was your choice in the original question to try the save the file to internal storage :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to store a file on the internal storage, which should be suitable for you. Use the `getFilesDir()` or the `getCacheDir()` method to get a `File` object representing the internal directory. Using a hard coded `String` for the `URI` is said to be bad practice.
If you need a Outputstream you can use the `openFileOutput()` method.

See the [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) website from Android Developers for further informations.

Comment: I'm not sure about: ArrayList<Pair<String, String>> position = new ArrayList<>();
            posisjon.add(new Pair<>(latitude, longitude)); and  for (Pair p : position)
                    oos.writeDouble(Double.valueOf(p)); is it the good method to add elements like i did? and oos.writeDouble(Double.valueOf(p)); is it correct?

Comment: This should give you a compile error as you are passing a `android.util.Pair` to `Double#valueOf(String)`.

Comment: I agree To Kristijan. You need to call p[i].first and p[i].second to get the stored values.

Comment: External permissions are of course NOT needed to write to internal memory. Please dont confuse the readers.

Comment: @greenapps  Reedited it. But as you can read in the comments below Kristijans answer, Steve wasn't sure whether he wants to store the files internal or external